# Error compiling and loading driver on the Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, sensor, kernel, driver

I bought a temperature sensor with a usb adapter and needed to install a driver for it, but I could not compile the driver provided by the manufacturer.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/CH341SER_LINUX $ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.4.11-v7+/build  M=/home/pi/CH341SER_LINUX
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.11-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

I tried downloading a linux headers and moving the /build folder to that directory, compiling worked, but I was unable to load. (Error: could not insert module ch34x.ko invalid module format)

The driver supports up to 3.14 kernel version and I have a 4.4 kernel installed. However I contacted the company that makes those usb adapters, and they said that the driver should support version 4.4. Here are the driver files.
[Driver download here](http://www.wch.cn/downfile/177)

I also followed the kernel building instructions on raspberrypi's official website using local building. But I don't know how to use the build function after following the instructions.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I was successful on compiling that driver following this guide

https://github.com/aperepel/raspberrypi-ch340-driver

following not "Section 1" BUT the section "Compilation Instructions".

Then I was able to tell RPI3 to use this compiled new driver instead of the one included by default (ch341) using the commands at the first part of this guide:

http://blog.poettner.de/2012/08/22/how-to-compile-rtl8192cu-ko-for-raspberry-pi-running-raspian/

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Even though I have already installed snappy ubuntu core on my Raspberry Pi to compile the driver.